# How to install own certificates into system certificates storage?

Tags: java, android, security

I would like to develop an own API for Android that will request "Signature" protection level and will be accessible for 'my" applications.

Idea is following:

1. "install" my own certificate into system certificates storage
2. sign "trusted" application with my own certificate

As a result during request from any application to my API system will check if this application is signed with an appropriate certificate. If my sertificate is installed into Android everything should be fine.

I'm going to prototype that approach, but if there is something obvious that can prevent me from doing that - please let me know.

**The question**:

how to install own certificate into system certificates storage (assuming we will build Android ourselves and can modify system (in a reasonable borders))?

Thank you very much.

P.S. I'm not very familiar with Java/Android development, so please don't mind if you see something strange.

**UPDATE:**

As I wrote in a comment to zeetoobiker's answer, If I sign my API with my own certificate then it will be accessible for all my applications (signed by my certificate), but it won't have any system permissions. And I don't want all my 'customers' to navigate to the "realmb.com/droidCert/" web site. Instead I want manufacturer to add my certificate into an OS, now I'm working on making a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to install the certificate.

From the [permission docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) for signature:

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the user's explicit approval.

This means that it's the certificate you use to sign the apps that matter (not any installed certificates) - if you sign App 1 and App 2 with the same certificate then it will have permission. If App 3 which is signed with a different certificate attempts to access the API then it will get a no permission exception.

According to the docs (I have to admit I've not done it although I'm looking at for some of my apps) it should work on vanilla Android without any necessary customisations / access to the device / root.

If you really need to install the root certificate, [this](http://www.realmb.com/droidCert/) may help but I don't think you do for your stated aim.

Comment: Hi Zeetoobiker, thank you for feedback. The reason why I need to install my own certificate into system storage is that I want my API to have some system permissions. If I sign my API with my own certificate then it will be accessible for all my applications (signed by my certificate), but it won't have any system permissions. And I don't want all my 'customers' navigate to the "http://www.realmb.com/droidCert/" web site. Instead I want manufacturer to add my certificate into an OS, now I'm working on making a proof of concept.

Comment: Please advise if you know how to install a root certificate into OS (on the compilation stage). Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't suggest heading to the website specifically, but the website (whilst also providing a way to achieve it) shows how you could add it - admittedly it means providing it to the system browser to download and install (it could be from the device itself).

Comment: As an API do you mean a small, non-visual interfacing app that exposes an API to other apps? I'm assuming that you do - if you mean something else, then could you explain that a little more? Because if you do mean that then the API app can have any system permission you want, you just need to request that in the manifest.

Comment: My API (let's better name it library, non visual app) is supposed to have an access to other system applications like Google Email, Calendar, etc. Yes, I know that I can request system level permissions for my library through the manifest. And I will also need to sign my library with the system certificate (to be a part of system, that is OK). But I also want 2 things: 1) my application should not be signed by system certificate (that is why I want to install my own certificate into system storage); 2) only application signed by my certificate should have access to my library.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense then - it appears you're trying to access system content not available normally - hence the need to use a new / additional system certificate. I think that's possible (I'd look at some of the mod community for that as creating your own ROM is probably the way you'd need to go) but I can't say for certain sorry.

Comment: It's OK. Thank you and looking forward having something from your side... actually working on compiling OS image myself... (with my colleagues).